# How to get “95%CI for a Binomial Proportion” using glm in R

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval, binomial-coefficients

I refer to the site [Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/11060_67f71d881707496cb3eeff3b4e595ceb.html)
Using glm in R, getting the ”asymptotic” 95%CI.
I think binomial link doesn’t have “identity”, but the following program got the answer. Why?
If you know that, please give me some advice.

This example, n=10, x=2, asymptiotic 95%CI

```
binom.ci<-function(x,n,alpha = 0.05,link="logit"){
z<-qnorm(1-alpha/2)
family<-binomial(link=link)
fit<-summary(glm(cbind(x,n-x)~1,family=family))
est<-fit$coef[,"Estimate"]
se<-fit$coef[,"Std. Error"]
family$linkinv(est+c(-z,z)*se)
}

binom.ci(x=2,n=10,link="identity")
# [1] -0.04791801  0.44791801
```

Comment: you can specify ```binomial(link="family")```.. whats the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have an "identity" link function with `binomial`, but it doesn't make much sense here. We can see what's going on inside the function if we replicate the `glm` call with the arguments in your example.

```r
fit <- summary(glm(cbind(2, 8) ~ 1,family = binomial("identity")))
fit
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = cbind(2, 8) ~ 1, family = binomial("identity"))
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#> [1]  0
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)   0.2000     0.1265   1.581    0.114
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 0  on 0  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 0  on 0  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 4.3947
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

The "identity" link means that the intercept is to be interpreted directly as a probability, but the problem is that taken literally, that means our 95% confidence interval includes a negative probability, which doesn't make any sense. We really need to use a logit link here to get the correct answer.

So yes, we can use `binomial(link = "identity")` here without it throwing an error, but it does not give us the classical 95% confidence interval for a binomial proportion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got it.